# How to model a Database View in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, service, repository-pattern, factory-pattern

I have to gradually replace an **ASP.NET Web Forms** application with an **ASP.NET MVC3 layered** application. Let's take into consideration just the **Repository** layer.

In my new **MVC application** I have one project for **Data** (name `MVC.Data`) and one for **Web**.

In the `MVC.Data` I have an **edmx file** with the EF classes, which models just the DB table (no views), and a Respository class `myRepository` which provides methods that perform simple queries.

In the old Web Forms application I have a `GridView` which is filled using as `DataSource` an **SQL database** view.

In order to have the same result in my new MVC3 application, I have two options:

1) Create a **Service layer** (and project `MVC.Services`), where I have a method that fill a new class `myViewClass` which contains all the fields of the SQL DB view and give it to the controller.

2) Create a class within the `MVC.Data` project which is directly filled by its constructor by using LINQ statements directly against the EF classes.

I read about the **factory pattern** and the 1st solution seems the most appropriate, however many people always suggest not to create a **Service Layer** if it is not needed. What is the best choice in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Actually building the view model should be done in a mapping layer. Basically your controller action might look like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    SomeDomainModel model = repository.GetSomeDomainModel();
    SomeViewModel vm = Mapper.Map<SomeDomainModel, SomeViewModel>(model);
    return View(vm);
}
```

The view model is defined in the MVC project as it is a class that is specifically designed to meet the requirements of the given view.

The `Mapper.Map<TSource, TDest>` method I have shown in my answer comes from [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) which I use in my project but you could define any custom mapping layer you like.

The mapping layer must also be part of the MVC project as it must be aware of both your domain models and your view models in order to perform the mapping.

As far as the service layer is concerned, you could use one when you have some complex business operations which could be composed of multiple simple repository calls. But some might argue for the existence of a service layer at all. I think that both approaches have their pros and cons that must be evaluated when designing a system and most importantly take into consideration the specific context and scenario you are designing.

Comment: thanks. Actually what I meant is not the ViewModel itself but the step before. I have a table Product with a ProductId field and the other fields as foreign keys to other tables. I have to make a Product class where all the foreign keys are replaced by the field name of that table

Comment: I see. I was confused by the name `myViewClass` that you used in your Service layer. Well in this case a service layer that will aggregate your transport entities (as they are no longer domain entities) into real domain objects might be the way to go.

Comment: I ask this because I watched the MVC Storefront video and it uses a class directly in the Repository composed by information taken by the domain model. I guess it just bypasses the service layer